# Credit Memo Missing in Invoice Magento 2.2.7

Tags: creditmemo, magento2.2.7

I'm using **Magento community version 2.2.7** for a multi-store website and for a completed credit card order with a paid invoice when I open the invoice to do an **online refund** the credit memo button is missing.

Questions we have about this issue:

- We were told Magneto 2 community versions do not have **online credit memos**, is that true?
- Our payment processor on our new websites is APS Payments and our APS account is currently set to test mode in the APS portal. Would having our APS account in test mode cause the credit memo button in the invoice to not show?
- How can this be fixed so we can issue online refunds/credit memos??